# CMMotionManager mixare camera pois always fixed on north (ios7)

Tags: ios7, camera, cmmotionmanager

I'm using mixare example to make an camera view with POI's on it. I did download mixare example posted here [Mixare example](https://github.com/mixare/mixare-iphone) and update and change UIAccelerometer code to CMMotionManager instead because it's not updated to work with recent sdk.

The problem is when i launch proyect, the radar is always fixed, and my camera show my POI on it but only because radar is watching the north and my POI is there on the radar. If y put more POI's on view not in the north, they appears on the radar, but I cant' make te camera turn to other position, it's always showing the North. **Radar never change orientation, is always see to the North, and my POI's is always on the same place on camera even if i move it.**

Please give me some ideas, i'm lost right now. Thanks

I did this on my code on my method "startListening:(CLLocationManager*)locManager"...

```
self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
self.motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.01; //en segundos
self.motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval = .1;          //en segundos
self.motionManager.magnetometerUpdateInterval = .2;


[self.motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error)
 {
     [self outputAccelertionData:accelerometerData.acceleration];
     if(error)
         NSLog(@"%@", error);
 }];


if (!self.centerCoordinate) {
    self.centerCoordinate = [[PoiItem alloc] initCoordinateWithRadialDistance:0 inclination:0 azimuth:0];
}
```

and on the outputAccelertionData method...

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    rollingZ  = (acceleration.z * kFilteringFactor) + (rollingZ  * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));
    rollingX = (acceleration.x * kFilteringFactorX) + (rollingX * (1.0 - kFilteringFactorX));
} else {
    rollingZ  = (acceleration.z * kFilteringFactor) + (rollingZ  * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));
    rollingX = (acceleration.y * kFilteringFactorX) + (rollingX * (1.0 - kFilteringFactorX));
}
if (rollingZ > 0.0) {
    self.centerCoordinate.inclination = atan(rollingX / rollingZ) + M_PI / 2.0;
} else if (rollingZ < 0.0) {
    self.centerCoordinate.inclination = atan(rollingX / rollingZ) - M_PI / 2.0;// + M_PI;
} else if (rollingX < 0) {
    self.centerCoordinate.inclination = M_PI/2.0;
} else if (rollingX >= 0) {
    self.centerCoordinate.inclination = 3 * M_PI/2.0;
}


[self outputAccelertionData:acceleration];
```